# Microsoft Access 2013 - Can not add new record through a subform

Tags: ms-access, foreign-key-relationship, subform

I followed the subform wizard to link the master field (which is the primary key of my table, an Autonumber, Long Integer) and the child field (which is the foreign key, a Number, Long Integer) and I know that they are linked properly because I can only browse the records of the subform where the child field is equal to the master field. And when I select to add new record I expect that the value of the master field and the value of the child field will be equal however the latter is set to #Size!.
What does that value (#Size!) mean and is there any way to fix it?
I also get a pop up error message when I try to add content, (title, message) = (Microsoft Access, Out of string space).

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is about programming really...

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, it was a problem of encoding. I changed the name of the linked fields to Latin characters and works fine.